# Помощь с кодом по основам работы с формой на PHP

Tags: php, html

Задание: С помощью формы спросите у пользователя год. После отправки определите, этот год високосный или нет. Сделайте так, чтобы при первом заходе на страницу в инпуте уже стоял текущий год.

Вот код, который у меня получился:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <input
        name="Year"
        value="<?php
            if (isset($_GET['Year']))
                echo $_GET['Year'];
            else echo date('Y') 
        ?>"
    >
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<?php if(!empty($_GET['Year'])){
    echo date('L', strtotime($_GET['Year']));
} ?>
```

Но какую бы дату я ни вводил, результат получается 0 - то есть год не високосный. У меня есть подозрение, что это определяется ещё до того, как я ввожу данные (то есть для текущего года) и после не обновляется, но что сделать чтобы исправить это я не понимаю.

Comment: Если вы проверите значение, которое возвращает strtotime, то заметите, что он распознаёт ваш год не как год, а как часы и минуты

Comment: strtotime принимает в себя определённый формат (см. в документации).  просто воткнуть в него год - неправильный формат

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо большое! Я был уверен, что так это и работает :) 
теперь всё работает как надо: 
echo date('L', mktime(00, 00, 00, 01, 01, $_GET['Year']));

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо большое, я бы ещё долго искал где ошибся

Comment: Можно было просто `strtotime($_GET['Year'] . '-01-01')`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский о, так я попытался сначала, но до конкатенации не дошёл, затупил с кавычками и решил сделать через mktime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть функция checkdate(), она может проверить, есть ли дата в календаре. Проверьте ей, есть ли 29 февраля нужного года:

```
checkdate(2, 29, $year)
```

например вот такое решение:

```
if(!empty($_GET['Year'])) {
    $year = intval($_GET['Year']);
    if(checkdate(2, 29, $year)) {
        echo "Год $year - високосный";
    } else {
        echo "Год $year - не високосный";
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Буду знать, очень полезная функция